# Unexpected results from GLKQuaternion conversion (from CMQuaternion)

Tags: ios, rotation, quaternions, core-motion

I'm working on an iOS app that will use CoreMotion to calculate range of motion.

I quickly abandoned Euler angles due to gimbal lock. So, now I'm trying to use quaternions.

As you probably know, `CMMotionManager` reports device motion data through the `CMDeviceMotion` class. The pertinent property here (for my purposes) is the `attitude` property, an instance of `CMAttitude`. From this, of course, you can access `pitch`, `roll` and `yaw`. I am still doing this when logging results just to get a better idea of the data that's coming off the device (since these values are fairly intuitive to envision). It also provides a `quaternion` property, which is an instance of `CMQuaternion`.

Based on many hours of research here and elsewhere, I was convinced that using quaternions was the correct approach to have correct results in any orientation. The problem is that I have found the `CMQuaternion` class/structure to be very dense and difficult to understand. Apple's documentation is sparse, and I couldn't ever back out what I considered to be a valid axis-angle representation from a `CMQuaternion`. (If someone has the math for calculating an axis-angle representation from a `CMQuaternion`, I'm all ears!)

I thought I had this issue solved when I stumbled across Apple's `GLKQuaternion` structure in their GLKit library. GLKit has methods that provide the axis and angle from an instance of `GLKQuaternion`. There's even a nice constructor method: `GLKQuaternionMake(x, y, z, w)`.

Since `CMQuaternion` had x, y, z, and w properties, I reasoned that I could use this method to basically "cast" between instances of `CMQuaternion` and `GLKQuaternion`. I'm still not sure if that was correct or not.

In any case, I was logging results from my iPhone when I came across some particularly weird results.

The code that I've written has the **intended** purpose of capturing an initial attitude (when the user taps a button) and then sampling the CoreMotion data and determining the difference between the starting position and the current position.

Here's the code:

```
- (void)sampleDeviceMotion {
    // I've tested this, and "self.startingAttitude" is set/reset correctly
    if (self.startingAttitude == nil) {
        self.startingAttitude = self.motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude;
    }

    CMQuaternion quaternion1  = self.startingAttitude.quaternion;
    GLKQuaternion q1          = GLKQuaternionMake(quaternion1.x, quaternion1.y, quaternion1.z, quaternion1.w);
    GLKVector3 v1             = GLKQuaternionAxis(q1);
    float angle1              = GLKQuaternionAngle(q1);

    CMQuaternion quaternion2  = self.motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.quaternion;
    GLKQuaternion q2          = GLKQuaternionMake(quaternion2.x, quaternion2.y, quaternion2.z, quaternion2.w);
    GLKVector3 v2             = GLKQuaternionAxis(q2);
    float angle2              = GLKQuaternionAngle(q2);

    float dotProduct          = GLKVector3DotProduct(v1, v2);
    float length1             = GLKVector3Length(v1);
    float length2             = GLKVector3Length(v2);
    float cosineOfTheta       = dotProduct / (length1 * length2);
    float theta               = acosf(cosineOfTheta);
    theta                     = radiansToDegrees(theta);

    float rotationDelta       = angle2 - angle1;
    rotationDelta             = radiansToDegrees(rotationDelta);

    printf("v1: (%.02f, %.02f, %.02f) v2: (%.02f, %.02f, %.02f) angle1: %.02f, angle2: %.02f - vectorDelta: %dº. rotationDelta: %dº (pitch: %.02f, roll: %.02f, yaw: %.02f)\n", v1.x, v1.y, v1.z, v2.x, v2.y, v2.z, angle1, angle2, (int)theta, (int)rotationDelta, self.motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.pitch, self.motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.roll, self.motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.yaw);

}
```

I've looked that code over 20 times, and I don't see any flaws in it, unless my assumption about the ability to move between `CMQuaternion` and `GLKQuaternion` is flawed.

I would expect that when the device is lying flat on a table, tapping the button and leaving the device still would give me results where `q1` and `q2` are essentially identical. I would understand a slight amount of "wobble" in the data, but if the device doesn't move, the axis and angle of the different quaternions should be (almost) the same.

Sometimes I get that (when the button is tapped and the device is left still), but sometimes the "initial" (`self.startingAttitude`) and subsequent values are off by a lot (40º-70º).

Also, in one case where the initial and subsequent values were in line, I had a weird result when then attempting to measure a rotation.

I "spun" the phone (rotation around the "Z" axis), and go the following results:

**BEFORE:**

> v1: (-0.03, -0.03, -1.00) v2: (0.01, -0.04, -1.00) angle1: 0.02, angle2: 0.01 - vectorDelta: 2º. rotationDelta: 0º (pitch: 0.00, roll: -0.00, yaw: -0.01)

**AFTER:**

> v1: (-0.03, -0.03, -1.00) v2: (-0.00, -0.01, 1.00) angle1: 0.02, angle2: 0.14 - vectorDelta: 176º. rotationDelta: 7º (pitch: -0.00, roll: -0.00, yaw: 0.14)

I believe the pitch/roll/yaw data to be correct both times. That is, I imparted a small amount of yaw rotation to the phone. So, why the did Z axis flip completely with just a small change in yaw?

Comment: I am not sure you can subtract angle2 and angle1 if the axes are different. I was looking at CMAttitude and its says it represents the relative change in orientation - I assume that is the quaternion you get. See this note: "Core Motion outputs a direction cosine matrix (DCM) — basically a rotation from the last "old" orientation to the new orientation of the device."

Comment: @SteveO'Connor I never did get a suitable answer to this issue, so I talked to my funding source, and we decided to write that app in a way that it limits the user to rotation around 1 axis. That way, we're confident with our calculations. Would still love an answer to this, though.